# simple decimal percentage loader

Tags: javascript

I was trying to achieve a simple percentage loader, but for some target value its providing wrongly!

Some correct value set scenario:

- target = 92.4, then the incremental function sets the element text as 92.4%
- target = 91.7, then the incremental function sets the element text as 90.8

Some wrong value set scenario:

- target = 90, then the incremental function sets the element text as 89.1%
- target = 91.7, then the incremental function sets the element text as 90.8%
- target = 100, then the incremental function sets the element text as 99.0%

My goal is to get the correct incremental value set in target as end result!

```
<div class="progress" />
function incrementLoader(target) {
        var value = 0,
        ment = parseFloat(target - value) / 100,
        elem = document.querySelector(".progress");

      var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (value >= parseFloat(target)) {
          return clearInterval(interval);
        }
        elem.textContent = `${parseFloat(value).toFixed(1)}%`;
        value = Math.fround(parseFloat(value + ment) * 100) / 100;
      }, 20);
}

incrementLoader(92.4);
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you reached the target value AFTER displaying it.

Comment: muratgu: As I always believe, another pair of eyes will certainly HELPS! Cheers mate Considering your suggestion and minor tweak to the code now its all working as expected.

Comment: but i wonder `var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (value >= parseFloat(target)) {
          return clearInterval(interval);
        }
        elem.textContent = `${parseFloat(value).toFixed(1)}%`;
        value = Math.fround(parseFloat(value + ment) * 100) / 100;
      }, 20);` if this be testable using Jest